# TestStack White error JAVA app

Tags: java, c#, automation, white-framework

I try TestStack.White to run an automation for JAVA app, here in my example is Calculator coded in JAVA, under VS2015 in C#. I installed TestStack.White using NuGet and tring with Winform app and it works, but here with java app, I can open the application, But not all component I can click on it.
So I try to know the component name with UIA Verify interface, but it selects the whole window, after that I look for something similar to UI Verify, and I found Ranorex STudio with Track Features and it works I can see Java Component name, but after I know the name, and I searsh for it in the app, the code not working. This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application aa = Application.Launch("..\\..\\CalculatorOrange.jar");
        Window calcWindos = aa.GetWindow("Calculator Lite - 1.5.3", InitializeOption.NoCache);

        Button twoBtn = calcWindos.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByText("8"));
        twoBtn.Click();
        //var twoBtn = calcWindos.Get<MenuBar>("mnuFile");
        //twoBtn.Click();
    }
}
```

and it shows this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'TestStack.White.AutomationException'
>   occurred in TestStack.White.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to get (ControlType=button or
>   ControlType=check box),Name=8

This image shows the component type and name
[image]

Update 1 : On the left, I use Ranorex Spy, and it shows all the Component, and on the right the Inspect for Microsoft
[image]

Comment: Could you please take a screen shot of what inspect.exe returns when hovering over the control. You can get inspect here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx and it installs to this location C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86.

Comment: For UIA Verify can recognize the button, but Ranorex Spy can, see the update

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to see what inspect.exe produces since it uses the ui automation com wrapper and is written by microsoft. UIAVerify is using the .net System.Windows.Automation namespace and I am not sure what Ranorex uses.

Comment: Ranorex have api, and it uses all .net ana java for Web, desktop and mobile, and it works perfect, but the problem I most pay to get Ranorex

Comment: have you built ur java app using swing?..If so, then go for SWTBot

Comment: I don't have the source code of the origin app